# Tratamento de string em posições alternadas

Tags: php, string, stringbuilder

Tenho uma saída que via EXPECT acesso um equipamento e recebo os dados abaixo:

```
$result1 = "

                    ===============================================================================
                    Service Basic Information
                    ===============================================================================
                    Service Id        : 1311                Vpn Id            : 0
                    Service Type      : Epipe               
                    Description       : xxxxxxxx
                    Customer Id       : 1312                
                    Last Status Change: 06/11/2017 10:51:13 
                    Last Mgmt Change  : 03/24/2017 19:22:10 
                    Admin State       : Up                  Oper State        : Up
                    MTU               : 9014                
                    MTU Check         : Enabled             
                    Vc Switching      : False               
                    SAP Count         : 1                   SDP Bind Count    : 1
                    Uplink Type:      : MPLS                

                    -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                    Service Access & Destination Points
                    -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                    Identifier                               Type         AdmMTU  OprMTU  Adm  Opr 
                    -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                    sap:lag-10:1311                          q-tag        9212    9212    Up   Up  
                    sdp:1019:1311 S(192.168.101.19)          n/a          0       9190    Up   Up  
                    ===============================================================================";
```

Porém dependendo do firmware do equipamento o resultado vem com algumas linhas em posições diferentes, entretanto os labels são sempre os mesmos.

Por exemplo quero extrair os valores 1311 referente ao Service Id e 9014 referente ao MTU,

Tentei com o seguinte código extrair o Service Id, porém o resultado da certo com 4 caracteres(1311) se for 5 caracteres(13211) já não funciona mais.

Alguém tem alguma ideia de como fazer isso?:

```
$result1 = preg_replace('!\s+!', ' ', $result1);
$posicao = strpos($result1, 'Service Id :');
$service_id_teste = substr($result1, $posicao+13, 4);
echo $service_id_teste;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você simplesmente utilizar o REGEX:

```
Service Id\s+:\s?([0-9]+)
```

Dessa forma:

```
preg_match('/Service Id\s+:\s?([0-9]+)/', $result1, $ServiceIds);

echo $ServiceIds['1'];
```

O `\s+` é o espaço, com qualquer tamanho, o `\s+?` é um espaço opcional, portanto `:1234` e `: 1234` são suportados. No fim, existe o `[0-9]+` é qualquer caractere entre `0` até `9` de qualquer tamanho.

Resultado:

```
1311
```

O mesmo pode ser feito com qualquer número, mesmo se for maior do que 3 caracteres.

---

Copiando o [@rray♦](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/212347/15089), onde a resposta usa o `|` (ou), que é realmente muito boa,e não havia pensando nesta possibilidade, você pode utilizar:

```
preg_match_all('/(Service Id|MTU)\s+:\s?([0-9]+)/', $result1, $matches);
```

Dessa forma, pode obter os valores usando:

```
preg_match_all('/(Service Id|MTU)\s+:\s?([0-9]+)/', $result1, $matches);

$valores = array_combine($matches['1'], $matches['2']);

echo $valores['MTU'];
echo PHP_EOL;
echo $valores['Service Id'];
```

Resultado:

```
9014
1311
```

[Teste isto.](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/c8b1cc33397e8d6b06cb7f37441aa9d293585103)

Comment: Perfeito! obrigado

Comment: com a edição ficou melhor explicado ainda... agradeço muito!

Answer (score 3):

Segue expressão regular e explicações:

```
<?php

/*...*/
// Busca pela linha onde tem o Service Id, está com ignore case, então pega maiúscula e minuscula. Depois, procura por um número que pode ser de 0-9 repetidas vezes, sem limite e coloca este na posição serviceId do array.
preg_match_all('/Service Id.*?(?P<serviceId>[0-9]+)/i', $result1, $output);

// Imprime o primeiro item encontrado, volta como array, por isso o current para ir para o primeiro elemento
echo (current($output['serviceId'])); //1311

?>
```

Acabei esquecendo de incluir o MTU, abaixo o exemplo pegando os dois valores e sendo nomeados:

```
<?php

/*...*/
// Exemplo pegando 2 itens, service Id e Mtu.
preg_match_all('/(Service Id.*?(?P<serviceId>[0-9]+)|mtu.*?(?P<mtu>[0-9]+))/i', $result1, $output);

// Como os itens foram setados nomeados, basta acessá-los como abaixo. Caso tenha um terceiro item
// bastaria manter a sequencia.. Ex.: $output['qualquerCoisa'][2]..[3]..[4]..
echo $output['serviceId'][0]; //1311
echo $output['mtu'][1];       // 9014

?>
```

Comment: Muito obrigado Bruno, ajudou bastante

Answer (score 3):

Pode usar uma regex para capturar as informações desejadas:

```
Service Id\s+:\s+\d{4,5}|MTU\s+:\s+\d{4,5}
```

O trecho acima diz para casar `Service Id` seguido de um ou mais espaços (`\s+`) seguido de dois pontos (`:`) seguido de 4 ou 5 dígitos (`\d{2,5}`) ou (`|`) casar `MTU` seguido de um ou mais espaços (`\s+`) seguido de outros 4 ou 5 dígitos (`\d{4,5}`)

```
preg_match_all('/Service Id\s+:\s+\d{4,5}|MTU\s+:\s+\d{4,5}/', trim($result1), $m);

echo "<pre>";
print_r($m);
```

Retorna o seguinte array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Service Id        : 1311
            [1] => MTU               : 9014
        )

)
```

Comment: Muito boa explicação! obrigado